# Can't create new use in docker

Tags: docker

I don't want to run my Docker container like root so decided to create new user for my image, this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-jdk-11-slim AS build_step
RUN mkdir /backend
COPY . /backend
WORKDIR /backend
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:x86_64-debianslim-jre-11.0.15_10
RUN mkdir /application
RUN addgroup --system javauser && adduser -S -s /bin/false -G javauser javauser
COPY --from=build_step /backend/target/my-java-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /application
WORKDIR /application
RUN chown -R javauser:javauser /app
USER javauser
CMD ["java", "-jar", "my-java-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

When I run it I get error:

```
Step 8/13 : RUN addgroup --system javauser && adduser -S -s /bin/false -G javauser javauser
 ---> Running in 92551640a19e
Adding group `javauser' (GID 101) ...
Done.
Option s is ambiguous (shell, system)
Option s is ambiguous (shell, system)
Option g is ambiguous (gecos, gid, group)
adduser [--home DIR] [--shell SHELL] [--no-create-home] [--uid ID]
[--firstuid ID] [--lastuid ID] [--gecos GECOS] [--ingroup GROUP | --gid ID]
[--disabled-password] [--disabled-login] [--add_extra_groups] USER
   Add a normal user

adduser --system [--home DIR] [--shell SHELL] [--no-create-home] [--uid ID]
[--gecos GECOS] [--group | --ingroup GROUP | --gid ID] [--disabled-password]
[--disabled-login] [--add_extra_groups] USER
   Add a system user

adduser --group [--gid ID] GROUP
addgroup [--gid ID] GROUP
   Add a user group

addgroup --system [--gid ID] GROUP
   Add a system group

adduser USER GROUP
   Add an existing user to an existing group

general options:
  --quiet | -q      don't give process information to stdout
  --force-badname   allow usernames which do not match the
                    NAME_REGEX configuration variable
  --help | -h       usage message
  --version | -v    version number and copyright
  --conf | -c FILE  use FILE as configuration file

The command '/bin/sh -c addgroup --system javauser && adduser -S -s /bin/false -G javauser javauser' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'backend' failed to build
```

Without it works perfectly. Anybody know what is the problem?

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously in this command:

```
adduser -S -s /bin/false -G javauser javauser
```

When it's run inside a container, the command complains because it does not support some of the parameters and prints a help.

Since you are basing your image off of `maven:3.8.5-jdk-11-slim`, the `adduser` command is whatever those people have chosen to put in this image and is likely a different version from what is on your local computer.

What you can do is to start an empty container with `docker run -it maven:3.8.5-jdk-11-slim /bin/bash`, and then experiment until you are satisfied with the result. Then put those commands in `Dockerfile`.

You can also use a different base image, or roll your own.